# Different values of similar functions

Tags: qutip

This question requires the knowledge of [GRAPE](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S1090780704003696). More info can be found [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/0kgrph09ghy5p74/khaneja2005GRAPE.pdf?dl=0) and in this short [presentation](https://www.dropbox.com/s/huuhqwtvg1bx2ag/grape_june_2010_slides.pdf?dl=0).
In the following [jupyter notebook](https://github.com/qutip/qutip-notebooks/blob/master/examples/control-grape-cnot.ipynb) the result of this line

> _overlap(result.U_f, U_f_numerical).real, abs(_overlap(result.U_f, U_f_numerical))**2

(which is in the "Test numerical integration of GRAPE pulse") the result obtained seems very low.
Why would the unitary obtained by the propagator function  "U_f_numerical" be so different from that derived from the cy_grape_unitary function "result.U_f"?
They are both derived from "result.H_t". I am saying that they seem to be different based on the low value "0.11355125771393167" of the _overlap function. I may be totally wrong about this. 
I have raised this as an [issue](https://github.com/qutip/qutip-notebooks/issues/81)

Comment: Hi Tejas!  Your questions seem pretty localized to GRAPE - whatever that is.  Maybe you could provide some explanation as to what GRAPE is?  I suspect there might not be enough people on this forum that can lend a hand.  Maybe revise your question to say... "GRAPE is a system for designing gradient ascent algorithms for NMR pulses.  There is a Mathematica notebook that lets one experiment with XXX.  However, when I try to use the notebook, I am getting inconsistent results.  In more detail, YYY."  Can you make it informative or interesting, even for those who don't know about GRAPE?

Comment: @MarkS added some resources about GRAPE. Please let me know if it is enough.